# Should package.json `name` and `version` be placed at the top level of JSON?

Tags: node.js, json, npm, package.json

If the name field is not placed at the top level in package.json file in the manner illustrated below , is it  recognized Or Not ?

Is there an npmjs specification indicating that these syntaxes are allowed?

```
{
  "dummy": {
    "name": "project"
  },
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

I read this page, but there was no description of how deep each field should be placed in package.json, and if there is no name, version field, etc.
https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That way `"name"` won't be recognized by most tooling, no.

Extensions not specified in the NPM `package.json` spec are allowed (but gently discouraged, IIRC).

Comment: `Extensions not specified in the NPM package.json spec are allowed` > If I create a "name-ext" that extends "name", is it possible to treat the contents of the field like a "name" field? I'm wondering how to find the "name" field in package.json.